# Error when we use pandas "apply" and "lambda" with Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, lambda, apply

We need to push a custom code from front end (Django) to back-end (Visual studio code which executes the python code). We are getting the below mentioned error when we use pandas "apply" and "lambda".
e.g

```
exec('''DFrame=pd.DataFrame({'A':['11','2','3'],'B':['X','Y','Z']})
print(DFrame.head())
def DD(X,Y):
 return X+Y
DFrame['C']=DFrame.apply(lambda x: DD(x['A'], x['B']), axis=1)
print(DFrame.head())''')
```

Error we are getting:

> NameError: name 'DD' is not defined

Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this?

Comment: Sorry, but it works well on my computer. Could you provide a picture of it?

Comment: Hi Steven, The issue is resolved now..The issue apparently is because of locals() or global() function call while executing the code in Jupyter notebook or Visual studio Code..Thank you for checking in!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using apply you can use either DD or lambda. For example, only using lambda:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['11','2','3'],'B':['1','2','3']}) 
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A'] + x['B'], axis=1)
```

The output of df would be:

```
    A  B    C
0  11  1  111
1   2  2   22
2   3  3   33
```

Comment: Hi Gray_Rhino,The issue is resolved now..The issue apparently is because of locals() or global() function call while executing the code in Jupyter notebook or Visual studio Code..Thank you for checking in!